# Storing a paragraph and keeping track of the number of occurences of each word

Tags: c++

I am wondering if anybody can suggest a way that I can store an entire paragraph of words and keep a count of the frequency of each word, and then sort the words in order of most frequent to least frequent. I think this could be done using a two dimensional array and maybe a structure to hold the counts, but I can't quite figure out an exact way to do this. I am currently coding on DevC++.

Comment: Well I haven't really tried anything yet because I'm trying to design it on paper to understand how it should work. I know I can make an array of structures, and store each unique word in a structure along with that word's count, but I can't figure out how to get it to increase that word's count for each occurrence of that word. I think it needs to search the paragraph for that word, but then how would I get it to search through the paragraph for the NEXT unique word?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `std::map` that maps `std::string` to `int`.  The `int` will be the count and the `string` is the key.  That would be an easy way to build the list of counts.  From there it should be straightforward to get your list of least to greatest.  You could make a pair from the map entries and place them in a vector, then just sort the vector on the count.  There may be some better ways to get the sorted count at the end, but that is what came to mind initially.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to count words frequences you need two data structures.

The first one is a `map` (you may use [`std::map<std::string, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), but if it's possible to use C++11, I would recommend [`std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). You collect your words and count number of occurences of each word.

After all words are processed you may use [`std::priority_queue<std::pair<std::string, int> >`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) and put all your words from the map in the this queue. Use a custom comparator to compare number of occurences:

```
 typedef std::pair<std::string, int> Element;
 struct LessOccur {
     bool operator<(const Element& _lhs, const Element& _rhs) {
         return _lhs.second < _rhs.second;
     }
 };
 std::priority_queue<Element, std::vector<Element>, LessOccur> pq;
 for(auto it: wordMap)
     pq.push(*it);
```

That's it.